# using jqgrid with res-api

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

hello i try to learn about jqgrid.

somehow what i code is didnt work. i read the description and follow the instruction but i cant get the data to display it inside the table.
my code is like this

```
<div style="margin-left:20px">
    <table id="jqGrid"></table>
    <div id="jqGridPager"></div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'http://interview.kargo.co.id/api.html',
    mtype: "GET",
    styleUI : 'Bootstrap',
    datatype: "jsonp",
    colModel: [
      { label: 'id', name: 'id', key: true, width: 75 },
      { label: 'vehiclegroup__name', name: 'vehiclegroup__name', width: 150 },
      { label: 'destination__name', name: 'destination__name', width: 150 },
      { label: 'departure__name', name: 'departure__name', width: 150 },
      { label:'metric', name: 'metric', width: 150 },
      { label:'start_date', name: 'start_date', width: 150 },
      { label:'end_date', name: 'end_date', width: 150 },
      { label:'price', name: 'price', width: 150 },
      { label:'loadcap__name', name: 'loadcap__name', width: 150 }
    ],
    viewrecords: true,
    height: 250,
    rowNum: 20,
    pager: "#jqGridPager"
  });
});
```

is it because the http://interview.kargo.co.id/api.html , is it api file?
please help me

Comment: The `url` you are providing, doesn't return data. It is an `html` page which prints data in its body.

Comment: so how to get the data sir? is any other way to get the data if i change the script?

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Type` of the response of the `url` is `text/html`. That's why the data is not loading.

I did not use jqGrid earlier. So can not help you much. I think you can load the data seperately like below:

```
var data = $.getJSON('http://interview.kargo.co.id/api.html')
```

and use [this example](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) (`Loading Data` > `Array Data`) to bind it to jqGrid.